# How can you logically group HTML elements without taking the help of CSS classes?

Tags: javascript, html

I know that in jQuery you can use something like $(".cssClass") to get all elements with this class. However in plain html and javascript how do you group elements logically? For example:

```
<input id="fee1" data-id="1" data-group="Fees" type="text" value="$15.00"/>
<input id="fee2" data-id="2" data-group="Fees" type="text" value="$25.00"/>
<input id="fee3" data-id="3" data-group="Fees" type="text" value="$35.00"/>
```

I want to create a javascript function like this:

```
function GetByDataGroup(dataGroup){
/*  returns something like [[1,"$15.00"],[2,"$25.00"],[3,"$35.00"]]*/
}
```

EDIT : Due to some political reasons I cant use jQuery or any framework..i know it doesnt make sense  :)

Comment: That's an HTML class. CSS has rule-sets, which have selectors, which might include class selectors. Classes themselves are pure HTML … and there are plenty of implementations of `getElementsByClassName` for browsers that don't have a native version out there.

Comment: @David Dorward : Sounds interesting but I dont understand fully.. can you elaborate/post an answer ? Sorry its my pea brain

Comment: Your question does not make sense as you are trying to avoid something which does not exist for reasons which are unspecified.

Comment: What are the political reasons? If there is another lib they prefer, use it's features... If it doesn't enable this basic functionality then you have reason to question why the other lib is being used.

Comment: some people are against using libs and like reinventing the wheel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of form elements like you've given in your example, the `<fieldset>` is the logical grouper.

Your form can (and some might go as far as to say 'should') have many fieldsets breaking up your form into logical areas.

Once you have the relevant form fields divided up into the logical `<fieldset>`'s you can grab these using your Javascript either through a class/id on the fieldset, or some other selector (perhaps you're grabbing all fieldsets on the page etc).

This makes it a lot easier if you're using Plain Old Javascript rather than a framework to grab those items by some kind of id. Consider:

```
<fieldset id="contactDetails">
  <input ... />
  <input ... />
  <input ... />
</fieldset>
```

Using your POJ you can get all of these from:

```
var contactDetails = document.getElementById('contactDetails');
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use another javascript framework? There are many: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks

You could use something like this:

```
function getElementsByClass(node,searchClass,tag) {
    var classElements = new Array();
    var els = node.getElementsByTagName(tag); // use "*" for all elements
    var pattern = new RegExp('\\b'+searchClass+'\\b');
    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++)
         if ( pattern.test(els[i].className) )
             classElements[classElements.length] = els[i];
    return classElements;
}
```

(from here: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=19294)

Comment: Use a version which looks for a native implementation of `getElementsByClassName` before looping over everything. It saves a lot of processing in modern browsers.